# the number of connected components

Tags: graph-theory

I am finding a solution of the following problem. I would like you to give a short proof.

Let A be the adjacency matrix of a d-regular graph G. Prove that d is an eigenvalue of A
with multiplicity at least the number of connected components of G.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the question, the answer is obvious. Denote by $n$ the number of the components of $G$. For every component $C$ of $G$, take the vector $[C]$ whose coefficient corresponding to a vertex $v\in G$ equals $1$ if $v\in C$, and $0$, otherwise. It is immediate that $A[C]=d[C]$. The linear subspace $S$ generated by all $[C]$'s is $n$-dimensional and $As=ds$ for any $s\in S$.

Comment: v vertex or edge? S means that?

Comment: The coefficients of the vector (= column) $[C]$ correspond to all the vertices $v$ of the graph $G$. By definition, $S$ is the  the linear subspace of columns generated by all $[C]$'s.

Comment: why multiplicity at least the number of connected components?

Comment: When you have a linear subspace $S$ of dimension $n$ such that $As=ds$ for all $s\in S$, the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $d$ of $A$ is at least $n$. This is elementary linear algebra. (To see this, you may write everything in the basis containing a basis of $S$.)